# Interesting tensor constructed from Ricci tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature

Does the tensor
$$\frac{1}{2}g^{\rho\lambda}(R_{\lambda\mu;\nu}+R_{\lambda\nu;\mu}-R_{\mu\nu;\lambda})$$
have any interesting uses in the context of General Relativity? This is a quantity which has an analogous algebraic structure to the Christoffel symbol, except instead of ordinary derivatives of the metric, we have covariant derivatives of the Ricci tensor. One interesting property is it is traceless in its $\mu,\nu$ indices (you can prove this using the contracted Bianchi identity).

In case you need some motivation to take this question seriously, I came across this structure when finding the variation of the conformal gravity action $\sim\int \sqrt{-g}C^2$ with respect to the metric, specifically when looking at possible boundary terms. Because of this context, it may have some nice properties under conformal transformations.